# Facebook Like Button Redirect

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

We gave a Facebook like button with the following setup:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.mydomain.com/mypage?id=123456" send="true" layout="button_count" width="134" show_faces="false" action="recommend" font=""></fb:like>
```

The URL http://www.mydomain.com/mypage?id=123456 actually points to a redirect which finally redirects the user to the final page.

When a user clicks the Like button Facebook displays the canonical URL of the final page and not  the URL specified in the href. Is there a way to stop this happening?

Answer (score 0):

> The URL `http://www.mydomain.com/mypage?id=123456` actually points to a redirect which finally redirects the user to the final page.

Are there any benefits from this to the user?

> Is there a way to stop this happening?

Only if you stop redirecting – either in general (if it has no benefits to the user, why do it in the first place), or specifically for the Facebook scraper (by [detecting it by it’s user agent](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#bestpractices)).

Comment: The redirects are for campaign specific URLs. This is used for internal reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a very difficult time with this when I was first starting out as a developer and probably came across this post once or twice too.

I made a tool for this exact purpose — as I thought it might be helpful to others:

[Facebook Like Button Generator](http://o-e.us/fb/lbg)

It generates (and stores) the open graph tag(s) so you don't need to put them in your page and the 'Redirect URL' tells it where to send all the traffic.

It detects the Facebook bot/scraper too so it won't interfere with anything.